# How do I SSH into this home router? Minimal web options, SSH connection reset by peer, telnet creates bad request

Tags: router, ssh, home-networking, telnet, network-monitoring

I'm looking to extract logs from my TP-Link Archer AX73 to do some basic network monitoring. I initially followed a guide involving an SNMP exporter but quickly discovered that there is no option to enable SNMP in the router's web interface from the browser.

A co-worker suggested SSHing into the router, but there is also no option in the web interface to enable SSH... So I tried searching the internet and poking around the command line:

- Documentation regarding [SSH](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2025/) and [SNMP](https://www.tp-link.com/us/configuration-guides/configuring_snmp_rmon/?configurationId=18105) related to TP Link hardware is all for their switches and doesn't apply to home router models' interfaces
- A couple of others have also tried SSHing into similar models ([one](https://community.tp-link.com/en/business/forum/topic/87844), [two](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/enable-ssh-for-tp-link-archer-axe75/164513/8)) and similarly had trouble determining how... At the time (earlier this year), some people utilized an [exploit that has since been patched](https://github.com/aaronsvk/CVE-2022-30075)
- SSHing into the router via port 443 yields **Connection reset by peer**, but there are no places in the web GUI where my machine is blacklisted or firewalled off

  ```
  ssh admin@192.168.0.1 -p 443
  kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
  Connection reset by 192.168.0.1 port 443
  ```
- SSHing on any other port other than 443 yields **Connection refused**.
- There *is* an option in the web GUI to enable "Local Management via HTTPS" , and some reading lead me to try accessing the router using the telnet command, but the connection is closed immediately after opening, without a chance to send any requests:

  ```
  telnet 192.168.0.1 443
  Trying 192.168.0.1...
  Connected to 192.168.0.1.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked

  B
  Bad Request
  0

  Connection closed by foreign host.
  ```
- same as above for `telnet 192.168.0.1 443 -a -l admin`
- changing the port for telnet yields “Connection refused”
- connecting via `nc` is successful...

  ```
  nc -vz 192.168.0.1 443 
  Connection to 192.168.0.1 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
  ```

Directly contacting TP-Link is my next step, but I wonder if any of the above results point to something more straightforwardly amendable. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you even think you can SSH into the router? Maybe there isn’t an SSH interface let alone SSH server on the router?

Comment: https://support.ipvanish.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017936053-How-to-retrieve-TP-Link-router-System-Logs

Comment: @Giacomo1968--I still have a lot to learn about networking, and it seems I made some incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik--I've found that menu option, but I was hoping to pull the logs directly (ideally automatically and periodically) to use in monitoring software that I'm learning to work with. I hear it may be possible to build a webscraper to get it from this web UI, but I'm not familiar with the process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SSHing into the router via port 443 ...

Port 443 is for HTTPS, and the router will likely serve the UI with a self-signed certificate. You will also likely see port 80 for HTTP access to the UI. Both of these interfaces will probably present the same UI, and you even mention "*There is an option in the web GUI to enable "Local Management via HTTPS"*".

Port 443 isn't going to behave if you try to connect with SSH or Telnet (you'll be "*speaking the wrong language*"). Using SSH or Telnet to connect to a webserver isn't going to work.

> SSHing on any other port other than 443 yields Connection refused

This isn't unexpected - if there is no service listening on the chosen port, you'll generally see results like "*connection refused*" or "*connection timeout*".

---

It's *very* likely that the router doesn't support SSH or Telnet at all (typically on port 22 or 23 respectively), this is a common situation for consumer equipment like this.

Searching for "*Archer AX73 SSH access*" doesnt show any useful results, so if port 22 isn't open, and there is no clear option in the web UI to enable it... then it's probably not available.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @Attie. Seems perhaps I was barking up the wrong tree altogether...

Comment: No problem! I hope it's all a little clearer now.